# KendoMultiSelect with DataSource Send All Items with Request

Tags: kendo-ui

I have been trying to implement a Kendo UI MultiSelect control with full read/write functionality for about three weeks now (as an evaluation at home in my own time). I have found this to be very challenging, in light of the paucity of examples of using the Kendo UI DataSource with the MultiSelect.

I am 90% of the way there. I just can’t seem to crack the update. When I add a couple of items, then click a submit button (which invokes the sync method of the DataSource), every item in the MultiSelect is forwarded to the server with the request as JSON. That is, every item which the Read returned, whether selected in the MultiSelect not.

Here are a few code snippets:

```
$(function () {

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "json",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/api/Members/Members',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "GET"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/Home/Update",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        create: {
            url: "/api/Members/Update",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function(data, type) {
            return kendo.stringify(data);
        }
    },

    batch: true,
    schema: {
        parse: function(response) {
            return JSON.parse(response);
        },
        model: {
            Id: 'Id'
        }
    }
});

var teeTimes =
$('#TeeOffTimes').kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "Select members...",
    dataTextField: "FirstName",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    autoBind: true,
    dataSource: ds,
    itemTemplate: $("#members-template").html(),
    value: ['1']
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");


$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    var val = teeTimes.value();
    ds.sync();
});
```

});

Is there a way to get the DataSource to submit only those items which the user has selected when it syncs? Or does it not work like that?

Thanks

Comment: When do you want to send update/delete/create requests to the server just after multi-select being modified or when a button is clicked?

Comment: @OnaBai I'd like to do the CRUD requests to the server when a button is clicked.

Comment: So I should understand that you originally have `op1` and `op2` and when you click you have `op1` and `op3`, you would be sending a `create` (for `op3`) and a `delete` (for `op2`). Correct?

Comment: @OnaBai Not quite. When the page loads, it immediately does a read via the DataSource. There is only one option visible - 'Rod'. When user clicks the Select, a drop-down drops with 3 items to choose from. 'Tom', 'Dick' and 'Harry'. User selects 'Harry'. So, only 'Rod' and 'Harry' are visible when the drop-down folds up. Then, the Submit button is clicked. All 4 'Rod', 'Tom', 'Dick' and 'Harry' are submitted to the server. Even though only 'Rod'' and 'Harry' have been selected by the user.
The widget does not seem to distinguish between selected options and available options.

Comment: All quiet here. No ideas?

Comment: Not sure. DataSource in a MultiSelect is intended for containing the list of valid values and not the list of selected values. You should think on this as a pure HTML select where you have multiple options in your HTML select *BUT* when you want to send the picked option(s) to the server you define a form and click submit. This is similar: you get the valid values but if you want to send back only the values picked then you have to write an `update` function that gets the value and sends it. Do you need help with this possible implementation?

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks. I believe I should be able to implement that. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't fighting against the technology. I got it in my head that all interactions should be via the DataSource, and not manual/custom. Not sure how to award an answer to a comment, but would like to chuck some recognition your way.